# Bootstrap button.js code understanding

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

Was just digging bootstrap 3.3.1 button.js source code, because I'd like to build a similar plugin.

You can check out the source code here: [source code ][1]

**My question:** now what is the following lines doing in the button.js source code :

```
 $(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
    var $btn = $(e.target)
    if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
    Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
    e.preventDefault()
  })
```

I went through the documentation of jQuery on function and even made a few examples for myself so that I understand it better , but somehow the above lines of code are a bit too complex for me to understand .

Now I ran a few tests using the button.js plugin: I wrote the following HTML :

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
```

and the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myButton").click(function(){
            $(this).button('loading').delay(1000).queue(function() {
                $(this).button('complete');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });        
        });
    });
```

Now of course all the above goes in the index.html file and I was importing the button.js file in a script tag.

Now when I click on the "click me" button, the button shows 'loading...' for 1 second (with the button in a disabled state), after that the button still shows 'loading...' but is enabled back again.

Now the important part of the test, I went to the source code of the button.js file and took off the following code (yeah the same piece of code that I am having difficulty understanding) :

```
$(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
    var $btn = $(e.target)
    if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
    Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
    e.preventDefault()
  })
```

Now I press the button 'click me' again, and the plugin still functions fine.

Now I have a feeling that bootstrap plugins are built in such a way that you can initialize them using jQuery or even data-attributes, and somehow I have a feeling also that this piece of code (sorry repeating the same piece of code for the again !! :D ):

```
 $(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
        var $btn = $(e.target)
        if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
        Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
        e.preventDefault()
      })
```

Has more to do with the "initializing the button.js plugin using data-attributes". But this is just a guess .

Thank you .

Alexander

```
[1]: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js#L16
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line-by-line explanation of the code below:

`$(document).on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {`

1. Create a *delegated event handler* that listens for a custom `click.bs.button.data-api` event to bubble up to the `document` element.
2. Filter the elements in bubble-chain (from clicked item up to document) to see if any element has a `data-toggle=` attribute that *starts with* the string `"button"`
3. Call the supplied function with `this` equaling the element that had `data-toggle=` on it. Note: `this` is ignored in the function.

`var $btn = $(e.target)`

4. `e.target` is the original object clicked. `$(this)` would have done the same job (unless the button had been wrapped). The code appears to allow for any number of DOM changes inside/outside the actual button.

`if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')`

5. If the clicked element does not have a class `btn` on the element, search the ancestors for the closest element that does have this class (this allows for buttons to wrap other elements).

`Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')`

6. Call a static `call` method within the `Plugin` namespace. In this case call the `toggle` method of the button.

`e.preventDefault()`

7. Stop the click from performing its normal action (might have been a link or submit otherwise).

*note: If you still have questions, make them specific*

Comment: ! Hey Thanks YOU :D :D hehe , That was really really very kind of you . :D